# How to compute the formula of common tangent plane of three spheres

Tags: geometry

Now there are three spheres, $s_0(x_0,y_0,z_0,r_0), s_1(x_1,y_1,z_1,r_1), s_2(x_2,y_2,z_2,r_2)$. $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ represents the center of the $i$th sphere,and $r_i$ is the radius. I want to calculate the formula of the common tangent planes of the three spheres. I don't know how. Please tell me the answers if you know. Thanks very much!

Comment: Please tell us what you’ve tried, if anything.

Answer (score 3):

See [Solving a common tangent problem using matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1129402/35416) for the corresponding planar situation. I'll adapt [one of my answers there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1130403/35416) to your 3d setup. I'll be a bit faster here than I was there, so if you feel lost, check out the 2d post first.

I'd do a bit of Lie sphere geometry. Encode a sphere as $(x,y,z,\pm r,x^2+y^2+z^2-r^2,1)^T$ or any multiple thereof. Notice how these are *oriented* spheres, and choosing the sign for each will lead to different solutions. (Flipping the signs of all the spheres doesn't change anything, though, so there are only $2^2=4$ sign combinations to consider, not $2^3=8$.) The point at infinity is $(0,0,0,0,1,0)^T$ and a “sphere” passing through that point will actually be a plane. Two spheres $a,b$ are in oriented contact if $a^T\cdot L\cdot b=0$ and a vector $a$ represents a sphere if it is not the null vector and $a^T\cdot L\cdot a=0$. The matrix $L$ used here has the form

$$L=\begin{pmatrix}-2&&&&&\\&-2&&&&\\&&-2&&&\\&&&2&&\\&&&&0&1\\&&&&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that other people do Lie geometry using different basis vectors, and different matrices for the bilinear form. Dividing the above matrix by $2$ is common, and choosing the basis in such a way that the matrix becomes diagonal with $\pm1$ along that diagonal is common, too. But I'll stick to what I described.

So now compute a matrix formed by $s_i^T\cdot L$ including the point at infinity as $s_3$:

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
-2x_0 & -2y_0 & -2z_0 & \pm2r_0 & 1 & x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2-r_0^2 \\
-2x_1 & -2y_1 & -2z_1 & \pm2r_1 & 1 & x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2-r_1^2 \\
-2x_2 & -2y_2 & -2z_2 & \pm2r_2 & 1 & x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2-r_2^2 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now you want a vector $v$ such that $M\cdot v=0$. The last row tells you immediately that the last coordinate of $v$ has to be zero. From the other rows you get an underdetermined set of equations for the other five elements of $v$. In general you will find a two-dimensional space of solutions here, or kernel of the matrix, if you prefer to think of it in these terms. Pick two vectors $v_1,v_2$ which are a basis of this kernel. Then find a solution to $(v_1+\lambda v_2)^T\cdot L\cdot (v_1+\lambda v_2)=0$. This is a quadratic equation in $\lambda$, so you will get two solutions here. (Actually one should also consider $\lambda=\infty$, so check whether $v_2^T\cdot L\cdot v_2=0$ is already a solution.) Combined with the four different choices of which spheres have same sign and which ones have different sign, you end up with up to $8$ common tangential planes.

But what does the vector actually encode? Suppose you have $v_1+\lambda v_2=(a,b,c,d,e,0)^T$. Then this encodes the plane $ax+by+cz=\frac12e$. The fourth coordinate isn't needed any more, it merely represents $d=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$, the oriented norm of the normal vector.